# Algolia: restore scroll down position

Tags: magento2, algolia

I scroll down algolia search page. After I click on some prodct and go to the product page. After I click Back button on browser and i see again algolia search page. I am excepting to see scroll down position(as it was before), but have Top.

I use Magento2 + Algolia(1.9.0)

Does anyone know what may be solution?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your best option is to save the scroll position:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
//set scroll position in session storage
sessionStorage.scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
});
var init = function () {
//return scroll position in session storage
$(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollPos || 0);
$(’.ap-dropdown-menu’).remove();

};
window.onload = init;
```

As described:

- https://discourse.algolia.com/t/instant-search-positioning-on-returning-to-page/4656
- https://discourse.algolia.com/t/instantsearch-vanilla-js-save-scroll-position-on-back-button/7401